# Ubuntu hardware market

Tags: hardware

Can anyone show me where I can find information about the computer hardware market with pre-installed Ubuntu software on it?  In other words, what is the current market like? How many units are expected to be sold in 2014, etc.

I know that the top selling companies in this market are: System 76, Zareason, Think Penguin and Emperor Linux.

Answer (score 4):

There is a list [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPre-installed) of sellers that supply Ubuntu hardware. As for top seller, you could compare share prices or something, there is an article [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/the-top-five-linux-desktop-vendors/9313) that may be of interest.

There is also a list of [Certified Hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/).